# What is "\C" with xelatex and beamer?

Tags: fonts, beamer, xetex

When compiling a beamer document using xelatex, I encountered a problem with the macro `\C`.  Basically, I want to use that to stand for the set of complex numbers so I want to redefine it to be `\mathbb{C}`, but `xelatex` complains that it is already defined.  Using `\show`, I can see that it is defined to be:

```
> \C=macro:
->\PU-cmd \C \PU\C .
```

but a texmf-wide grep doesn't show me anything sensible on what that actually means!  So I don't know if it's safe to clobber it or not.

Here's the minimal test case.  Note that the issue only shows up with `xelatex`, not with `pdflatex` or `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\show\C
\end{document}
```

It feels like something font-y, since if I remove the `\show` (i.e., actually try to *use* the command), then I get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \C unavailable in encoding OT1.
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

\C is defined in puenc.def from hyperref and is e.g. loaded if you use the "unicode" option which beamer does probably if you run xelatex. It encodes U+030F "COMBINING DOUBLE GRAVE ACCENT". The same unicode char is encoded in puenc.def by \textdoublegrave and \G. \textdoublegrave is also defined in T3 encoding (tipa). I don't know if \C and \G are defined in other packages. You can probably safely redefine it, but I personally avoid to define one-char commands as they are often used for accents commands.

Comment: I take your point about the one-char commands, but I use ℂ far more than I use a "combining double grave accent"!